# MySQL query returns a string as a result of JSON_OBJECT()

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I wrote a query that gives me posts from a table and also returns an info about each post's author:

```
SELECT post.id, post.text, post.datetime, JSON_OBJECT(
                'username', user.username,
                'firstName', user.firstName,
                'firstName', user.lastName) as author
                FROM post
                INNER JOIN user ON post.authorId = user.id;
```

But in response the `author` field is a string:

```
author: "{"username": "@", "firstName": null}"
datetime: "2017-05-02T20:23:23.000Z"
id: 10
text: "5555"
```

I tried to fix that using `CAST` but anyway `author` is a string:

```
CAST(JSON_OBJECT(
    'username', user.username,
    'firstName', user.firstName,
    'firstName', user.lastName) as JSON) as author
```

Why is it happened and how to fix that?

UPD:

I send the data from server using Node.js and Express:

```
app.get('/posts', (req, res, next) => {
    getPosts().then((posts) => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(posts);
    })
    .catch(next);
});

   // ...

getPosts() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const query = `
            SELECT post.id, post.text, post.datetime, JSON_OBJECT(
                'username', user.username,
                'firstName', user.firstName,
                'firstName', user.lastName) as author
                FROM post
                INNER JOIN user ON post.authorId = user.id;`;
            this.connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if(err) {
                    return reject(new Error("An error occured getting the posts: " + err));
                }

                console.log(result) // prints author as a string 

                resolve(result || []);
            });
        });
    }
```

Result of `console.log`:

```
{
    id: 1,
    text: 'hello, world!',
    datetime: 2017-05-02T15:08:34.000Z,
    author: '{"username": "@", "firstName": null}' 
}
```

I also tried here change `res.send(posts)` to `res.json(posts)` but it's doesn't help.

My function from client that touch server for the posts:

```
export const getPosts = () => {
    customFetch(apiUrl + '/posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json)
};
```

Comment: Probably something specific to the programming language you are using. What is it BTW?

Comment: I use javascript

Comment: I am not a node expert but my understanding is that it has multiple different ways of connecting to an RDBMS sadly what you have chosen does not seem to support json objects. JSON after all is a some what recent addition to mysql

Comment: I agree with @e4c5 , this is probably due to how json objects returned by MySQL are handled by the client. You probably have to explicitly convert the string to json in js code.

Comment: @Shadow I already do that. I updated my post and added a function from the client that touch server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's fine for MySQL to return a string, as the `JSON_OBJECT()` function is already doing its job by producing a string that represents a well formatted JSON.

You can convert that string to a JSON object in javascript with

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourString);
```

**Edit (about JSON and Javascript objects)**

First of all, in case you didn't know, JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation: that means that it's a textual way of representing JavaScript objects.

From MySQL point of view, you're already solving this problem inside the `SELECT` statement, because what the query is returning is a valid JSON.

The fact is that then that data is transmitted to Javascript (Node), but Javascript internal representation of an object is not the same as its textual representation (the JSON); this means you have to "cast" it, so that the string gets converted to the object.

The mechanism you'd need in order to avoid this cast would require MySQL to know how Javascript represents an object, and then using such knowledge to return the bytecode of your object. This is called serialization, and I'm afraid it's way beyond the purpose of a dbms like MySQL.

Hope this clarifies your doubts a bit...

Comment: I do that `response => response.json()`. Or you mean I have to look for each key in my json that can be also json and use `JSON.parse` for them too?

Comment: Yes, the whole response won't be a valid JSON, but the `author` field surely will.

Comment: Okay, I get data from the table, iterate over data and modify each author using `JSON.parse(post.author)` and send it to the client. That works fine now, but it's looks so strange. Is there really no way to solve a problem inside of `SELECT`?

Comment: I edited my answer, it was way to long for a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Used JSON typeCast in the DB config file

```
  connection: {
    ..
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    ..
    typeCast: function (field, next) {
      if (field.type == 'JSON') {
        return (JSON.parse(field.string())); 
      }
      return next();
    },
    ..
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the right choice if your result contains both fields and JSON_OBJECT.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning the whole thing as a JSON_OBJECT and doing JSON.Parse on it once

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT("id", post.id, "text", post.text, "datetime", post.datetime, "author", JSON_OBJECT(
            'username', user.username,
            'firstName', user.firstName,
            'firstName', user.lastName))
            FROM post
            INNER JOIN user ON post.authorId = user.id;
```

That eliminates your need to loop